# how to test for empty / null values in xml with php

Tags: php, xml, if-statement, null

I have a webservice from where I retrieve informations before updating a database.

I have to search for some values before inserting them, if i found them, obviously I will not insert them the xml should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <categories>
    <category id="10" xlink:href="http://www.server.it/B2B/api/categories/10"/>
    </categories>
```

if it's full, otherwise :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<categories>
</categories>
</prestashop>
```

after retrieve the xml i make :

```
$resources = $xml->children()->children();


if ($resources->category[@id] == ""){
insert category
}
```

now, all this code is working perfectly, but I must admit that those `==""` is a bit awful, am I testing it in the right way? or is better some other kind of test? like `isset`, or `null` or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would try to insert the category if it's empty but I think this is what you mean:

```
if(isset($resources->category[@id]) && !empty($resources->category[@id])){

    //insert category

}
```

Comment: eheh sorry, i was not so clear, i check if it exist already on that server this is a sort of "sync" of two different places, so if something is present in place A must be in B otherwise, i insert it :D

Comment: may i ask you why you are testing both isset and empty? does a attribute with an empty value is considered set?

Comment: If a key exists in an array, that means it is set. However it could still be an empty value, so if you check both you know the key contains something. Hope this helps.

Comment: @DanielWade: This is [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement) so not an array (just [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess)). Also `isset(expr) && !empty(expr)` can be written as just `!empty(expr)`. see http://php.net/empty ; http://php.net/isset

Comment: @Hakre, fair comment. I thought it generated an E_WARNING if you checked !empty on something that didn't exist.

Comment: @DanielWade: I thought so, that's why I left the comment. And it's `E_NOTICE` ;) Just saying, not clever-shitting here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if there are *any* `category` children in the `categories` element, you can just test for that:

```
$category = $xml->categories->category;
```

The number of those `category` child-elements can then be retrieved via the `count()` function:

```
if ($category->count()) {
    echo "ID: ", $category['id'];
}
```

alternatively you can just explicitly look for that first element:

```
$category = $xml->categories->category[0]
```

The `$category` variable will be `NULL` if it does not exists, otherwise it's the XML element:

```
if ($category = $xml->categories->category[0]) {
    // insert $category
}
```

Hope this is helpful.